# Scale and the models of the hyperbolic plane

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I was reading somewhere (sorry I always forget where) that the scale of the Poincare Half plane is y (the vertical)

So at the boundary line the scale  is  $ 0 $ or $ ( 1 : \infty ) $.

at the horocycle $ y = 1 $ the scale is $1:1$ and

at $ y = \infty $ the scale is $ \infty$ and all vertical lines and hypercycles meet .

now I was wondering what is the scale function for the other models of the hyperbolic plane, escpecially for the  Poincare disk model and the Klein disk model?